# Netbeans Ant build.compiler.emacs

Tags: netbeans, emacs, ant, jikes

The default ant settings in Netbeans has the property `build.compiler.emacs` set to `true`. What does this mean? The ant documentation just says

> Enable emacs-compatible error messages.

I understand emacs is an editor, though I have not used it. What is the effect of setting this property to true or false?

Answer (score 3):

You might not have noticed that that part of the [ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) describing the javac task is in the "Jikes notes". It's a setting that modifies the result message format of a compilation while using the [jikes](http://jikes.sourceforge.net/) compiler in a way that when ant is invoked by the Emacs editor (e.g. while using the [JDEE environment](http://jdee.sourceforge.net)), the editor can parse the result messages and jump at correct positions in the files related to the messages.

It is indeed a bit weird that NB includes such a setting for a compiler that is not the standard one and seems abandoned for almost a decade.

Given the following ant `build.xml` file

```
<project name="mini" basedir="." default="compile">
  <property name="build.compiler.emacs" value="off"/>
  <property name="build.compiler" value="jikes"/><!-- invoke jikes instead of javac-->
  <target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="." destdir="" classpath="." includeantruntime="false">
    </javac>
  </target>
</project>
```

The compilation of a simple class comporting a syntax error gives that output:

```
Buildfile: /Users/seb/projets/java/ant/build.xml

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/seb/projets/java/ant
    [javac] 
    [javac] Found 1 semantic error compiling "Hello.java":
    [javac] 
    [javac]      5.                 System.out.println("Hello, World!"+foo);
    [javac]                                                            ^-^
    [javac] *** Semantic Error: No accessible field named "foo" was found in type "Hello".

BUILD FAILED
/Users/seb/projets/java/ant/build.xml:5: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

While you have this output by changing `build.compiler.emacs` property to `on`:

```
Buildfile: /Users/seb/projets/java/ant/build.xml

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/seb/projets/java/ant
    [javac] Hello.java:5:52:5:54: Semantic Error: No accessible field named "foo" was found in type "Hello".

BUILD FAILED
/Users/seb/projets/java/ant/build.xml:5: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

In the latter version, the messages are less fancy and Emacs is more capable of parsing them.